# Flashing 500 Internal Server Error to screen Flask with Python

Tags: python, flask

simple question I hope...
I am getting 500 Internal Errors when developing and want to flash them to the browser screen for easier turn around time. Whats the easiest way to do this with Flask with Python?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write custome error page in flask jinja template and show the way you want to flash on your screen

```
from flask import render_template

@app.errorhandler(500)
def page_not_found(e):
    return render_template('500.html'), 404

#An example template might be this for your 5000.html, you can write 
#your own through this code:

{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Page Not Found{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
  <h1>Page Not Found</h1>
  <p>What you were looking for is just not there.
  <p><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">go somewhere nice</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Wasn’t sure what the easiest way would be, but this will probably work, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

500 that means there something wrong in your demo.may as well put your error message